# Insegnare/impartire or fare una lezione: which is more commonly used?

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference when using *insegnare*, *impartire*, or *fare* to say that you are teaching a lesson? If not, which is more commonly used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Insegnare* takes as its object the subject being taught, rather than the word *lezione*, as in *Insegno il francese a Gianni*. *Impartire una lezione* is quite formal (the original meaning of *impartire* being “to share (something) among several people”), while *fare* is on the colloquial side; a good middle course to say “to give a lecture” is *tenere una lezione*.

Answer (score 3):

When someone teaches something he/she is "teaching", so "sta insegnando". 
"Impartire" is very very formal, and when talking it is not used a lot. 
"Fare" a lesson, is instead informal, such as "the teacher is *doing* a lesson". I'm Italian!

Answer (score 2):

The most commonly used among the three, while talking, is *Insegnare*.
For instance:

> *Insegno* inglese all'università

which would be a good answer if somebody asks "what's your job?" or, if they know you are a teacher, "what do you teach?".

If you want to express the fact that the course is happening right now, in this period of time, with a continuity concept, the best verb would be *Tenere*.
So it would sound something like this:

> In questo periodo sto *tenendo* un corso di inglese all'università

or, for instance if somebody calls you during a class

> Non posso rispondere ora, sto *tenendo* una lezione all'università

*Impartire*, as somebody else said, is unusual for verbal conversation, since it's archaic and very formal.
*Fare* is very generic and my Italian teacher used to suggest we find more specific verbs, since it's always possible. To use often *Fare* is a symptom of a scarce vocabulary, so it's better to avoid it when you have a better and more specific alternative.

Comment: "sto tenendo una lezione" ha connotati regionali. Non si direbbe al nord

Comment: Io sono di Milano e non ci vedo nulla di strano.
Rispondendo al telefono dire: "Scusami, ma adesso non posso... sto tenendo una lezione di..." mi sembra italiano corretto, a prescindere dalla regione